# Javascript onkeydown function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Why is it impossible to move the canvas circle? just provide me with tips what's wrong with listener. i understand that i've done some bad mistakes but nevermind them,i just can't understand principe behind changing position of object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>epicGame</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600px" height="600px" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
function drawCircle(){
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fill();
}
var velX=50;
var Player1={
    x:150,
    y:70,
    velX:20,
    velY:5,
    hp:20,
    startAngle:40,
};
function drawPlayer1(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(Player1.x,Player1.y,Player1.startAngle,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.fill();
}
function move(key){
    if(key.keyCode=="32"){
        updatePosition();
    }
}
function updatePosition(){
    Player1.x+=Player1.velX;
        ctx.arc(Player1.x,Player1.y,Player1.startAngle,0,2*Math.PI);
}
drawPlayer1();

window.addEventListener("keydown",move,false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have your checked if the handler is being run? If it's being run, have your checked if the condition in the handler is true? If it is, have your checked if your update function is working?

Comment: You also appear to only every draw the player once. Have your checked if the values are being updated, but the player is just not being drawn again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add "px"(unit) to the width and height of the canvas

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

You forgot to redraw the canvas when you press the key

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

// since the circle are always red, set ctx.fillStyle to red
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';

var Player1={
    x: 150,
    y: 70,
    velX: 20,
    velY: 5,
    hp: 20,
    startAngle: 40,
};

function drawPlayer1(){

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(Player1.x, Player1.y, Player1.startAngle, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
}

function move(event){

    // the event.keyCode is Deprecated, use event.code or event.key
    if(event.code === 'Space' || event.key === ' '){
        updatePosition();
    }
}

function updatePosition(){

    // update Player1's property
    Player1.x += Player1.velX;

    // erase the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    // redraw Player1
    drawPlayer1();
}

// bind event
window.addEventListener('keydown', move, false);

// initialize
drawPlayer1();
```

For more infomation about KeyboardEvent, go to MDN [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)